# Get user time for process group in c and windows

Tags: c, windows, time, process, shared-memory

In Unix I can call [`times()`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?times+2) to get not only the running time of the current process, but also that of the whole process group.

In Windows, I can call [`GetProcessTimes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the time of the current process. However, the documentation seems to indicate that this doesn't return the running time of the whole process group.

So is there any way I can get the running time of a process, and all of it's children in windows?

Comment: I believe you can get this information if you put the process in a job (before it launches the children).  Windows doesn't ordinarily keep track of the parent/child relationship to the extent Unix does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Harry said, this can't be done, at least not directly, because Windows does not track the parent/child relationship between processes like Unix does.

However, you can work around this by creating shared memory for processes, and have them both update that location as they go along. Here is where you can find more [documentation on shared memory in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).